# Exception Messages

Tags: struts2

I want to display Custom pages with custom message when exception is raised.
For this i am doing like this.

Action Class:

```
catch(OrbytTvException e) {
    result=NONE;
    Error err=new Error();
    err.setErrMsg("Exception Occured");
    log.info(err.getErrMsg());
    request.setAttribute("error", err);
}
```

Struts.xml:

```
<result name="none">/WEB-INF/pages/error.jsp</result>
```

Error ---- This is a bean contains errMsg property.

When exception raised here I am setting one value to that property.

Error.jsp:

```
<s:bean name="com.sits.itv.util.Error" var="errorBean" />
  <s:property value="#errorBean.errMsg"/>
```

Here i am displaying the errMsg but it display null.

Could you please help me how to display the custom message in struts2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to show the exception at the UI, s2 provides a clean way to do that,By default, the `ExceptionMappingInterceptor` adds the following values to the Value Stack:

1. exception   The exception object itself
2. exceptionStack  The value from the stack trace

and this is all you need to do in your JSP page

```
<s:property value="%{exception.message}"/>
  <s:property value="%{exceptionStack}"/>
```

for details refer to official doc

- [exception-configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/exception-configuration.html)
- [exception-handling](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/exception-handling.html)

additionally you need not to do  `request.setAttribute("error", err);` as S2 provides a clean, all you need to declare a property in your action class with its getter and setters and you are free to reefer them in your JSP as that property will be provides as part of Value-stack.

But still i believe that should not be the way to show information to the user and its always better to use framework provides way which is more flexible and easy to use

Comment: Thanks for your replay.could you please provide me reference urls for developing exception handling in strut2

Comment: @rams: Exception handling is nothing different in S2 and there is no specific exception you are required to throw under S2, you are virtually free to throw any exception and i already have provides 2 references in my answer which explain thoroughly how to handle and show information to end user